# Trying to estimate the path of a projectile with equations on graphic calculator. Need help

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, projectile, models

When a projectile is released with a very high velocity, it will not follow basic projectile motion because the Earth’s curvature will hinder those equations. In a crude sense, the Earth will curve before the projectile touches it, and thus the projectile has to travel further before it can crash on the Earth. As the Earth curves, the direction of gravitational acceleration g also changes.

I have been trying to find the parametric equations (the parameter is time(t)) for a ballistic projectile which was released horizontally with a velocity v from an altitude a above the Earth. I am using Desmos to create the graphs, which is a fiarly weak tool for such applications but I would like to stick to it and see if I can perform this small experiment.

Note: The earth is placed at $(0, −6.4 · 10^6)$ and has a radius of $6.4 · 10^6$ units. The projectile is launched from $(0, a)$

The equations (I think they are all correct) I have found so far are:

\begin{eqnarray} 
\theta &=& \tan^{-1} (\frac{y+6.4 \cdot 10^6}{x})\\
y &=& a - \frac{(g \cdot \sin(\theta))}{2}t^2\\
x &=& v \cdot t - \frac{(\cos(\theta) \cdot g)}{2}t^2\\
\end{eqnarray}

Gravitational acceleration equation might be useful though I didn't find it any helpful:
$$g = \frac{G \cdot M}{(y + 6.4 \cdot 10^6)^2 + (x)^2} $$

Since the direction of acceleration is constantly changing as we move forward in the $x$ direction, Here, $θ$ is the angle between the horizontal and the imaginary line from the projectile to the centre at any point in time.

[image: Ballistic Projectile]

Also, $θ$ is a function of time, but I cannot find a way to represent it like that because $x, y \: \text{and} \: θ$ are interdependent on each other. I have been scratching my head for the last
few hours with absolutely no clue what to do. Any help with this problem would be highly appreciated!

I am ignoring air resistance though I don’t think it will be very tough to add it to the equation. Anyways, please ignore it.

[Link to the graph where I didn't understand what I was doing :)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qlqvk3ixdi)

Comment: First  the starting velocity should be less than  8km/h otherwise ir will fly away. 2. why not use polar coordinates  so you have just r(t) and $\phi(t)$ I think desmos can handle them

Comment: I echo @trula on this.  It’s hard to find help and hard to visualize your solution because anyone trying to accomplish this is using polar coords. Otherwise you are “time-derivating” the X and Y components of gravity.  Polar makes the origin of your system coincident with the origin of your most complicated force (gravity.)  Making the initial position of the projectile your origin just complicated *everything.*  If you’re doing this just for the curiosity of a thought experiment, solve the problem first with polar coords and then figure out the polar-to-Cartesian transformations next.